# How to convert time format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ to MM-DD-YY and standard time

Tags: javascript, time

I have a time format returning from MySQL at 
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

So it looks like this

2017-02-17T22:32:25.000Z

When I run split() on it, it does nothing so

```
var test = data[i].createdAt;

test.split("T");
```

It does nothing to it

So I want the data to look like this

2017-02-17T22:32:25.000Z

to

02-17-2017 10:32 p.m.

Any help?

Comment: split doesn't modify its argument; instead it returns the array. Also be aware that `Z` denotes UTC time, not local time, so if you do just a formatting like you suggest, you'll still not have the time in the local time zone.

Comment: If some standard function doesn't seem to be working, why not read [some documentation for that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to see if you're using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `new Date(dateString)` and `dateObj.toLocaleTimeString([locales[, options]])`:

```js
var date = new Date('2017-02-17T22:32:25.000Z');
var formatOptions = { 
       day:    '2-digit', 
       month:  '2-digit', 
       year:   'numeric',
       hour:   '2-digit', 
       minute: '2-digit',
       hour12: true 
};
var dateString = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', formatOptions);
// => "02/17/2017, 11:32 PM"

dateString = dateString.replace(',', '')
                       .replace('PM', 'p.m.')
                       .replace('AM', 'a.m.');
// => "02/17/2017 11:32 p.m."

console.log(dateString);
```

- [`Date.parse(dateString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)
- [`dateObj.toLocaleTimeString([locales[, options]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript `Date` object will accept ISO dates like yours, at which point you can then just manually format the string like so:

```js
function formatDate(d) {
    var myDate = new Date(d);
    var hrs = ((myDate.getHours() > 12) ? myDate.getHours()-12 : myDate.getHours());
    var amPM = ((myDate.getHours() >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM");

    if (hrs==0) hrs = 12;

    var formattedDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + myDate.getDate() + "-" + myDate.getFullYear() + " " + hrs + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + " " + amPM;

    return formattedDate;
}

var myFormattedDate = formatDate("2017-02-17T22:32:25.000Z");
alert(myFormattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not averse to using a Javascript library, I would highly recommend Moment: http://momentjs.com. For your use case, the code would be:

```
var time = moment(data[i].createdAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');
```

It handles multiple time formats (on input and output) as well as edge cases.

Comment: @JuanMendes True, but date and time formatting can be an involved topic. Depending on the OP's use case, this may be the perfect solution without diving into a rabbit hole of date formatting and calendar edge cases.

Comment: It may be, that's why I think suggesting a library is at best a comment, it's not an answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) providing it the optional arguments. For instance:

```js
var dt = '2017-02-17T22:32:25.000Z';
console.log(new Date(dt).toLocaleString('en-CA', { hour12:true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleDateString` and `toLocaleTimeString` with or without some options. In contrast with `toLocaleString` this allows you to not include a comma.

```js
const str = '2017-02-17T22:32:25.000Z';
const d = new Date(str);

console.log(`${d.toLocaleDateString()} ${d.toLocaleTimeString()}`);

console.log(`${d.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g,'-')} ${d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'})}`);
```